# How to make two date fields related to each other?

Tags: 7, datetime

H have a content type with a start date and an end date.
How can make the

`end date defaut value` adjusting depending on what is entered on the

`start date choosen value`, ensuring that

`end_date always > start_date`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Date](https://www.drupal.org/project/date) module to create multi date field, Check this [article](https://www.lullabot.com/articles/whats-new-in-date-and-calendar-for-drupal-7) for more information